# Find the minimum concentration so that it doesn't precipitate

Tags: equilibrium, solubility, concentration, salt

> Calculate the solubility of silver chloride.
> a) in pure water
> b) Calculate the minimum concentration of ammonia that prevents precipitation in a solution that
> contains $0.1$ mol of AgNO3 and $0.01$ mol of NaCl per litre. Data: Kf [Ag(NH3)2+] = $1.6×10^7$ Ksp(AgCl)= $1.8×10^{−10}$

For part a) I'm totally sure on how do it: $$AgCl\rightarrow Ag^+ +Cl^-$$ $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ s \ \ \ \ \ \ s$$ $K_s=s^2\implies s=\sqrt{K_s}$

But for part b) I'm really stuck, I've tried $$\ce{Ag^+ +2NH3 \rightarrow Ag(NH3)2}$$ and $$\ce{AgCl\rightarrow Ag+ +Cl-}$$ but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: $\ce{[Cl-]} = \pu{0.01 mol}$, when you only consider one liter of the solution

Comment: yes so then we can find the $[Ag^+]$ with the constant of solubility which gives $1.8*10^{-8}$ but then I don't know what to do

Comment: You also know Kf, can you do something with that?

Comment: @SafdarFaisal something like this maybe? $K_f=\frac{1.8*10^{-8}x}{x}$ but I'm unsure since we didn't know the moles of $\ce{Ag(NH3)2}$ either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure water, you have probably seen that $s \ce{= 1.34·10^{-5} M}$.
In a solution containing $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in concentration $0.01$ M, the concentration in $\ce{Ag+}$ is then :

$$[\ce{Ag+}] = \frac{K_\mathrm{s}}{[\ce{Cl^-}]} = \frac{1.8 \times 10^{-10}}{0.01} = 1.8 \times 10^{-8}$$

The definition of $K_\mathrm{f}\ce{(Ag(NH3)2^+)}$ is

$$K_f = \frac{[\ce{Ag(NH3)2^+}]}{[\ce{Ag^+}][\ce{NH3}]^2} = 1.6\times 10^7$$

so that the critical concentration of $\ce{NH3}$ is given by:

$$[\ce{NH3}]^2 = \frac{[\ce{Ag(NH3)2^+}]}{[\ce{Ag+}]\cdot K_\mathrm{f}} = \frac{0.1}{1.8\times 10^{-8}\times 1.6\times10^7} = 0.347$$

The final $\ce{NH3}$ concentration is $\sqrt{0.347} = \pu{0.59 M}$

Comment: The value of $K_\mathrm{s}$ given was $1.8 \times 10^{-10}$, I took the liberty to change that

Comment: @Maurice amazing! But why is $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2+]}=0.1$?

Comment: @ Aley20. Silver ions are present under two forms : $\ce{Ag^+}$ and $\ce{Ag(NH3)2^+}$. The total of these two ions is $0.1$ . But, as $\ce{[Ag^+] =  1.8 · 10^{-8}}$, this value is negligible with respect to $0.1$, so that $\ce{[Ag(NH3)2^+]}$ is practically equal to $0.1$

Comment: @Maurice oh okay! So does it always add up to 0.1 or is it only because we had 0.1M of $\ce{AgNO3}$? I'm guessing the latter but I want to be sure.

Comment: @ Aley20. You are right. The given value ($0.1 M$), is the concentration in $\ce{AgNO3}$.